# Compiling Cairo-dock errors on GTK dependency

Tags: linux, gtk, redhat, cairo

I've Redhat 7.2 running Cinnamon, and hate the docks provided, how come I can't resize the area a widgit is allocated?  All apps are jammed into half the dock.

Drives me to compile cairo-dock from source as it isn't an ibm redhat blessed package.

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr
...
-- checking for module 'wayland-client>=1.0.0'
--   package 'wayland-client>=1.0.0' not found
-- checking for module 'gtk+-3.0>=3.4.0'
--   package 'gtk+-3.0>=3.4.0' not found
```

so I find gtk version is 3.14.13-16.el7 using yum list installed "gtk*"

I downloaded gtk 3.4.4 and compiled it and follow the INSTALL provided, sudo make install, which completes with no errors

rerunning cmake gives me the same error, so I'm wondering if I had to remove 3.14?  I'm not really sure how best to proceed and thought it best to get some advice.  I'm not really in the mood to break things.  Thanks for your time and consideration.

Comment: Did you forget to install the GTK+ and Wayland development files from yum? I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: good point, I was assuming make install would do that.

Comment: Don't overwrite your OS's version of GTK+ with your own (it's likely going to be newer); if you're going to experiment you should install to a separate prefix instead. Did installing the system development files fix it with the system libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calvin, I'm also IBMer and installed RHEL7.2 from IBM's image.

I could successfully download the sources and install Cairo Docker and respective plugins.
I followed the instructions in this page here:
[Glx-Dock - Generic:Compilation](http://glx-dock.org/ww_page.php?p=By%20compiling&lang=en#4-Generic:%20Compilation)

First, install all dependencies below from official IBM repository.

I used the same package names for the Fedora dependencies and some may NOT exist for RHEL. Therefore, some plugins won't be available by fetching dependencies from official repository only - but the Cairo Docker will work.

```
sudo yum install cmake make pkgconfig gcc gcc-c++ gettext glib2-devel\
cairo-devel librsvg2-devel dbus-glib-devel libxml2-devel libXrender-devel\
mesa-libGL-devel mesa-libGLU-devel pango-devel libXxf86vm-devel\
libXtst-devel libXrandr-devel libX11-devel libcurl-devel gtk3-devel\
vte3-devel lm_sensors-devel libxklavier-devel libexif-devel\
libetpan-devel gnome-menus-devel alsa-lib-devel libical-devel\
upower-devel libzeitgeist-devel
```

Untar the packages and build with the commands described there except that you need to force the lib64 in both main and plugin builds with:

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr -DFORCE_LIB64=yes
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a huge hint and got me 98% through dependency hell.  I was able to get core to compile but plugins was balking at version missmatch, so I started over cloning both from git and everything works excellent.